# Зачем использовать StringBuilder.ToString()?

Tags: c#

Не буду писать длинное предисловие, поэтому, собственно, сабж.
Изучаю С# по 6-му изданию книги Эндрю Троелсена. Пока что никаких проблем с пониманием материала нет (программирую на другом языке), но вот один момент я всё же не могу понять. Эндрю Троелсен в одном из примеров использует вызов метода `StringBuilder.ToString()` при выводе на экран переменных этого типа. Зачем вообще использовать `StringBuilder` я понимаю, так же как и его отличия от `string`. Но запись

```
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

в результате выводит в окне консоли то же самое, что и

```
Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

где `sb` - переменная типа `StringBuilder`. Я понимаю, что по сути `sb` является объектом, и вызывая метод `ToString()` этого объекта, я получаю готовую строку на выходе. Но зачем это делать, если и так всё работает? Какие недостатки могут быть, если не вызывать метод `ToString()`?

Но что-то я всё равно не понимаю, видимо, так как переменная типа `string` так же, как и `StringBuilder`, является объектом, и на деле я обращался к методам этого объекта. Но ничто не мешало мне просто выводить строку, без предварительных вызовов:

```
string myStr = "This is String";
Console.WriteLine(myStr);
```

Да и сам Троелсен тоже выводит переменные типа `string` без использования метода `ToString()`, который, кстати, тоже присутствует в переменных типа `string`. Так что же именно я не понимаю?

Comment: Всего лишь явное указание на получение строки. Явное лучше неявного.

Comment: Можно установить ReSharper, он в числе прочего будет  выдавать подсказки типа "ненужный вызов ToString, и без него нормально будет работать"

Comment: @ixSci а зачем вопрос-то было редактировать? Неужели мне нельзя быть вежливым? Хотелось бы оспорить ваше изменение.

Comment: @intro94, вежливым быть можно и нужно, а вот писать приветствия и прощания — не стоит. Это мешает восприятию текста. Если хочется оспорить моё действие, обратитесь к модераторам, они часто сидят в [этом](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) чате.

Comment: @ixSci, странно. Вы первый, кто говорит мне, что упомянутые вами обращения мешают восприятию. Да и повседневно, работая, я общаюсь с разными людьми - почти все они используют такие обращения, и никто из нас не путается. :)

Comment: @intro94, я рекомендую обратиться в чат, который я упомянул ранее, там Вам ссылок накидают почему мои действия оправданы и почему тут так принято. Я просто не смог сходу найти этого обсуждения, а там ребята Вас быстро снабдят нужной информацией.

Comment: @ixSci, спасибо, так и сделаю. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Полагаю, что в данном случае это лишь для наглядности приведено.
Общий смысл таков, что внутри `Console.WriteLine` для объектов все равно вызывается `ToString`.

Можете провести эксперимент, написав что-то такое:

```
MyObject o = new MyObject();
Console.WriteLine(o);
Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
```

где `MyObject` объект с переопределенным `ToString`:

```
public override string ToString(){
    Console.WriteLine("ToString called");
    return "foo";
}
```

Вывод будет такой:

> ToString called
>
> foo
>
> ToString called
>
> foo

Как видим, он одинаков в обоих случаях, в первом случае внутри `WriteLine` вызовется `ToString` объекта `MyObject`, во втором случае вы его явно вызываете и в `WriteLine` придет уже `String`, а для строк есть отдельный вариант этого метода (даже если бы не было, то `ToString` у `String` возвращает саму себя)

Comment: Хм. Теперь понял. Странно, тогда, почему Троелсен не говорил, что `Console.WriteLine()` вызывает метод `ToString()`. Да и в доках .NET 4 на MSDN об этом тоже не говорится. Именно из-за этого и возникли сомнения. Но в любом случае, вы помогли мне развеять сомнения, за что я вам благодарен. :)

Comment: @intro94, это есть в [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/swx4tc5e(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @ixSci, именно её я и читал. Не вижу там ничего про `ToString()`. :)

Comment: @intro94, _If value is null, only the line terminator is written. Otherwise, the **ToString method of value is called** to produce its string representation, and the resulting string is written to the standard output stream._

Comment: @ixSci, согласен, забираю свои слова обратно. Но тому что я это не видел есть две причины: 1. я использую справку встроенную в Visual Studio, а она, насколько я понял, отсекает всё то, что не на выбранном языке написано. 2. Я просто в английском не силён, так что, если есть русские доки, всё что на англ. написано почти всегда пропускаю.

Comment: @iksuy "все равно вызывается ToString" - не верно. Если передать строку, то вызовется другой метод, перегруженный для строки. В этом случае ToString не будет вызываться внутри.

Comment: @georgepolevoy, вы до конца принципиально не читаете?

Comment: @iksuy читаю, но в этот раз мне не потребовалось читать до конца, чтобы прочесть: "внутри Console.WriteLine для объектов все равно вызывается ToString". Это поправьте, и все будет норм.

Answer (score 2):

Строго говоря, когда я пишу `Console.WriteLine(sb);`, то даю компилятору самому выбрать из набора методов WriteLine() тот который больше всего подойдёт под параметр типа StringBuilder. Т.е. здесь я неявно подразумеваю, что будет преобразование в строку. Читая такую строку в коде я всякий раз мысленно буду говорить себе "а тут преобразование в строку".

Если же я пишу `Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());`, то я даю ему выбрать уже только из вариантов метода, принимающего первым параметром string. Т.е. во втором случае контроль разработчика над кодом чуть выше, и код чуть прозрачнее. Читая эту строчку, в голове лишних мыслей не возникает, и это хорошо :)